# split li elements in group of 3

Tags: php, for-loop, switch-statement, grouping

I have elements in `li`, they are generated using for loop

but I wanted to split them in group of 3

Like, but I could not achieve this using for loop so I used manual switch case for eg,
apply row1 for case between 1 and 3 than apply class row2 for case between 4 to 6 but if 
there are many products it will increase `li` and I need to write switch case for each group, so is there any way I can write a dynamic for loop or switch case?

```
<li class="row1"></li>
<li class="row1"></li>
<li class="row1"></li>

<li class="row2"></li>
<li class="row2"></li>
<li class="row2"></li>

<li class="row3"></li>
<li class="row3"></li>
<li class="row3"></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work like this.

```
 <?php for( $i=1; $i<=length of your product;i++)
    {
    $k=0;
        while($k<=3)
    { ?>
        <Li class="row<?php echo $i;?>"></li>

    <?php $k++;
    }
    } ?>
```

Comment: in this case there will be four `<li>` instead of 3 because you have `$k<=3` but it should be `$k < 3` because you use zero for `$k` or `$k` should be one :)

Comment: use $k<3 and $i++ and works fine

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with 2 for loops, eg:

```
for ($row_id = 1; $row_id <= 3; $row_id++) { // row ids 
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { // number of list elements you want with each row id
    echo '<li class="row' . $row_id . '"></li>';
  }
}
```

or if you actually wanted them into three seperate lists:

```
for ($row_id = 1; $row_id <= 3; $row_id++) { // row ids 
  echo '<ul>';
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { // number of list elements you want with each row id
    echo '<li class="row' . $row_id . '"></li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Not 100% sure what you're after from the wording of your question.

Answer (score 0):

M not a big fan of switches, i mould have prefered  [**MOD**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) functionality to achieve it like below

```
    echo "<ul>";
    <?php
    $obj = 0;
    while(//condition)
    {
        echo "<Li class=row.'$obj'></li>";
        if(++$obj % 3 == 0)
        {
           echo"</ul><ul>"; //create new ul list

        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<?php 
$k = 0; 

for ($i=1; $i < 12; $i++) { 

if($i%3==0){ $k++; echo " $k multiple times <br/>"; }

}

?>
```

Comment: `$i` should be one instead of zero. Also `$k++;` should be `$j++`

Comment: Sorry mistake while copying code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$k = array('a','b','d','f','bh','r','rr','rrr','eee','www','wwwww','qww','qwq','wqq','wq','qwq','wqw','wqeqwe','aew','qq','wqq','wqwq');
?>
<ul>
<?php
$s=1;
for($i=0;$i<count($k)-1;$i++)
{
    if($i % 3==0){
        $s++; 
    }
    ?>
    <li class="<? echo "row".$s?>"><?=$k[$i]?></li>
    <?php   
}
?>

</ul>
```

in page source see output like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="row2">a</li>
        <li class="row2">b</li>
        <li class="row2">d</li>
        <li class="row3">f</li>
        <li class="row3">bh</li>
        <li class="row3">r</li>
        <li class="row4">rr</li>
        <li class="row4">rrr</li>
        <li class="row4">eee</li>
        <li class="row5">www</li>
        <li class="row5">wwwww</li>
        <li class="row5">qww</li>
        <li class="row6">qwq</li>
        <li class="row6">wqq</li>
        <li class="row6">wq</li>
        <li class="row7">qwq</li>
        <li class="row7">wqw</li>
        <li class="row7">wqeqwe</li>
        <li class="row8">aew</li>
        <li class="row8">qq</li>
        <li class="row8">wqq</li>

</ul>
```